# HttpResponse of StringIO contents in Django

Tags: django, nginx

I have strange behavior now. Say, I have zip archive binary data in **StringIO**. If I set **content** parameter of **HttpResponse** to **StringIO.getvalue()**, I get truncated file on the client side. The same result with **StringIO.read()** and **FileWrapper(StringIO)**. The size of truncated files varies every time... I get the right file if I read the file from disk **FileWrapper(file('/home/user1/tempfile.zip'))**. But I need to generate zip file on the fly!

*Django 1.4, Nginx 1.1.19*

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this:

```
import zipfile
from cStringIO import StringIO
from contextlib import closing
from django.http import HttpResponse


def foo(request):
    ...
    with closing(StringIO()) as ff:
        zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(ff, 'a')
        for i, wb in enumerate(workbooks):
            with closing(StringIO()) as f:
                wb.save(f)
                zipped.writestr('%s.xls' % (i + 1), f.getvalue())
        zipped.close()
        foo = ff.getvalue()
    filename = 'foo.zip'
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="application/zip")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment;filename=%s" % filename
    response.write(foo)
    return response
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.